# Running Safari from the command line adds current directory to the URL

Tags: macos, safari

I am trying to run the Safari browser (on Mac OS 10.4) from the command line, as follows:

```
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari http://localhost/dev/myfile.html
```

However, Safari starts up and tries to access

```
file:///Users/charlesanderson/scripts/http://localhost/dev/myfile.html
```

/Users/charlesanderson/scripts happens to be my current directory.

Can someone explain why Safari does this? Firefox is much better behaved.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Starting Safari with arguments isn't supported or documented, AFAIK.

It's interpreting the first argument as a path (you'll notice that if you begin it with a `/`, it doesn't prepend the working directory).

If you just want Safari to navigate to a URL, use `open`:

```
open -a Safari <url>
```

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
open -a Safari URL
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `open` also handles URI protocols directly:

```
open http://google.com
# or
open 'http://google.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on macOS Catalina, Version 10.15.4:

`open -a Safari http://192.168.64.2:31818`

Just an FYI, I tried it with a `www` and it wouldn't work:

`open -a Safari www.192.168.64.2:31818`